# Does storyboard alter code functionality in xcode?

Tags: xcode, storyboard

I recently tried to get into developing iOS apps and I wanted to make a flashlight app so I was follow some tutorial. However the tutorial does the app without use of the storyboard. When i tried to do the same thing in storyboard I couldn't. So i thought if i just copied the logic from the header/delegate classes then the functionality should transfer! But when i tried running the storyboard version the program pauses/crashes and shows me the main class with a little bubble saying:
"Thread 1: SIGABRT"

Is there any reason that doing a project with storyboard alters the basic logic? Doesnt seem to make any sense

Comment: The biggest change, probably what you're seeing, is that without storyboarding, XCode using a .xib file for each view in your app. However, when using a storyboard, all of these .xib files are replaced with a single .storyboard file which contains the layout information for all of your views.

Comment: Your problem is most likely not that the code was altered by the storyboards, but you use code that works with xib files without having the xib files. Copy and pasting only works if you copy and paste everything. If you want to adopt a tutorial to storyboard you have to understand the code so you can make the necessary changes.

Answer (score 0):

From Apple's [UIViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/initWithNibName%3abundle) class reference:

> If your app uses a storyboard to define a view controller and its
>   associated views, your app never initializes objects of that class
>   directly. Instead, view controllers are either instantiated by the
>   storyboard—either automatically by iOS when a segue is triggered or
>   programmatically when your app calls the storyboard object’s
>   instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: method. When instantiating a
>   view controller from a storyboard, iOS initializes the new view
>   controller by calling its initWithCoder: method instead. iOS
>   automatically sets the nibName property to a nib file stored inside
>   the storyboard.

Comment: Just to clarify this answer, a common problem when switching to storyboards is that it may not be obvious that the storyboard is only calling "initWithCoder:". If you're using a different initializer, you may need to move your code.